# Why does my __init__ function need to be @classmethod?

Tags: python, inheritance

Here is a code snippet I wrote as a test. I noticed that if I don't define the init method as a classmethod, the code doesn't run:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.add(1)

    @classmethod
    def add(self, arg):
        self.value += arg

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def add(self, arg):
        self.value += arg * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    print a.value
    print b.value
```

This outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inherit.py", line 17, in <module>
    a = A()
  File "inherit.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.add(1)
  File "inherit.py", line 8, in add
    self.value += arg
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'value'
```

However if I change my init function to be `@classmethod`, the code works as intended:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod 
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.add(1)

    @classmethod
    def add(self, arg):
        self.value += arg

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def add(self, arg):
        self.value += arg * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    print a.value
    print b.value
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

I was under the impression init was by default a class method whose first argument must be self. What is going on?

Comment: I don't think you understand what a classmethod is.  `__init__` is not a class method by default, and none of the methods in your code should be classmethods either.

Comment: It's probably not working quite as expected. Try the following: `a1 = A(); a2 = A(); a1.add(1); assert a1.value == a2.value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have `add` marked as a `classmethod`, but it isn't.  Take out the `@classmethod` from the `add`s and it should work.

Comment: To expand on this, when `add` is marked as a `classmethod`, the call `self.add(1)` is not passing `self`, but `self.__class__`, as the first argument to `add`. It updates (or tries to update) the value of `A.value`, rather than `a.value` or `b.value`.

Comment: To further expand, making `__init__` a classmethod seems to help because in that case setting `self.value` inside `__init__` is actually setting `A.value` rather than `a.value`, making it accessible from the `add` classmethod.